# Using array type in Postgres with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, arrays, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using Postgres DB with SQLAlchemy as toolkit.

My model looks like

```
class Test(db.Model):

    """Test entry in DB."""
    __tablename__ = 'test'

    key1 = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    key2 = db.Column(postgresql.ARRAY(JSON))
```

I want to know how can I add elements to my `key2` column which is an array?

For making changes to the DB, let's say I am using something of this kind:

```
test = Test(key1="key2", key2=array)

db.session.add(test)
```

How can I add new elements to this array or make a new array and assign it to `key2`? Basically struggling with proper documentation for JSON Arrays in Postgres/SQLAlchemy.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Since JSON itself supports lists, do you have a specific reason for wrapping it in an ARRAY (for example having to work against existing schema)?

Comment: @IljaEverilä :- I want to store a list of JSON objects in key2. The issue I am facing is of casting. 
array = []
array.append(somedata)
test = Test(sha=actual_commit_sha, data=array)

It complains ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "data" is of type json[] but expression is of type text[]
LINE 1: ...NTO test (key1, key2) VALUES ('1223!4&&5678!^^^^', ARRAY['{"i...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I was just trying to point out that you could also store lists of objects in a `Column(JSON)` column as well, but JSON lists do not support slicing, if that is required. With your current model you can use an explicit CAST-expression: `test = Test(key1="key2", key2=sqlalchemy.cast(array, postgresql.ARRAY(JSON)))`, but that is a bit ugly.

Comment: @IljaEverilä :- Thanks. I am using Column(JSON) to store list of objects. But encountering an issue. 
My JSON doc is basically a list like this [{u'initiator': u'akchay', u'title': u'Test1'}, {u'initiator': u'akchay', u'title': u'Test2}]. Now when I want to update this list, and add another dictionary to it, then the update does not seem to happen.
event_row = Test.query.filter_by(key1="key1").first()
event_list = event_row.key2 //key2 is JSON doc 
event_list.append(third_dictionary)
event_row.key2 = event_list 
db.session.commit()
There is no update. Can you let me know what's wrong?

Comment: A super late reply, but: you (probably) lack [mutation tracking](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/mutable.html) for starters. Also when you assign `event_list` back to `event_row.key2`, you're just assigning the same list back, which in the eyes of SQLA isn't a change at all.

Comment: @IljaEverilä: big thanks for pointing out that I can store a list of objects in a `column(JSON)` - my mistake was that I was trying to do that using `column(ARRAY(JSON))`